# HTML: How relative url in <script> tag choose to go http or https

Tags: javascript, html, angular, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a simple angular app deployed on EC2 via nginx **over HTTP**.

I can load index.html of my application but after that, I have a timeout because the browser **try to load my local js and css files in https**.

In the meantime, I can access those files by directly by http url.

Here my index.html file, all script tags in the end of the file are in timeout, by the way, this code is generated by angular using ng build.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>App</title>
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="private">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <style type="text/css">
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Roboto';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-display: swap;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v29/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');
                unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
            }
        </style>
        <style type="text/css">
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Material Icons';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v109/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2) format('woff2');
            }

            .material-icons {
                font-family: 'Material Icons';
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
                font-size: 24px;
                line-height: 1;
                letter-spacing: normal;
                text-transform: none;
                display: inline-block;
                white-space: nowrap;
                word-wrap: normal;
                direction: ltr;
                -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            }
        </style>
        <style>
            .mat-typography {
                font: 400 14px/20px Roboto,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;
                letter-spacing: normal;
            }

            body,html {
                height: 100%;
            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
                font-family: Roboto,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.c9ba96590e65260d312d.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">
        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.c9ba96590e65260d312d.css">
        </noscript>
    </head>
    <body class="mat-typography">
        <app-root></app-root>
        <script src="runtime.ef25a47480c49459801d.js" defer></script>
        <script src="polyfills.0ea1f9479d3febcbc4f9.js" defer></script>
        <script src="main.cea65f9f3d64664e2cce.js" defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you !

Comment: If you land on a `http` address, it will stay on a `http`, unless you get a redirect on the server end.

Comment: You have `upgrade-insecure-requests` in your html file. Which directs the browser to move to `https`.

Comment: Yes, thank you Richard